# React Native Expo fetch() error Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-native, native

I try to fetch data from an external server using fetsh() in React Native. My query looks like this:

```
fetch('https://xxx.xx/login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
   if(responseJson === 'Data Matched'){
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { Email: email});
    }else{
     Alert.alert(responseJson);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return error;
  });
```

during the execution on my Android Device I get the following error:

```
  Network request failed
  Stack trace:
  node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:505:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

When I open the file in the browser, everything works without problems.

I am glad about your help.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Lukas

Comment: You have `https://https://` in the url, why?

Comment: Sorry, I only have https:// once. While changing the domain i accidentally wrote https:// twice. In my original code, it's only once.

Comment: Are you saying that you're opening login.php in the browser? As that would be using a GET HTTP method and not the POST method you're using in the fetch

Comment: @Mike W Yes but so i saw that the file is accessible

Comment: @Lukas have you checked that the server responds to POST requests and is returning something. Maybe try using Postman or curl as the error suggest a network request problem and your code looks fine

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it is a certificate error. If I use Postman i get the following error: "Error: Unable to verify the first certificate"
If I disable the ssl option it works (is this also possible in react native?). Do you know the reason? I use a normal certificate orderd from DigiCert.

Comment: I am getting the same issue only in POST requests from ANDROID and iOS. another request like GET works fine without issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a long search I have now found the solution. Through a test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest of my certificate I have received the following message:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

I uploaded my Certificate to https://certificatechain.io/ and added the .crt file to my SSL Configuration on my webserver. Now all works fine for me.

Hope I can help you with this.

Comment: I had the same message from **SSLLABS** and could fix it by adding the _intermediate_certificate_ to the SSL configurations.